# How to set jwt token in WWW-Authenticate in hapijs?

Tags: node.js, jwt, hapi.js, bearer-token, www-authenticate

I am able to create jwt on successful user login. But when I am using jwt strategy for other routes, I am getting 'WWW-Authenticate →Token' in the header also error comes :

```
{
    "statusCode": 401,
    "error": "Unauthorized",
    "message": "Missing authentication"
}



 {
    method: 'GET',
    path: '/example',
    config: {
        auth: {
            strategy: 'jwt'
        },
        handler: function(request,
        reply){
            returnreply('Success,
            youcanaccessasecureroute!');
        }
    }
}
```

If anybody knew how I remove this error please reply.

Comment: You have to send the token in the request `Authorization` header.

Comment: Thanks, its done. Do you have any idea of setting 'hapi-auth-bearer-token' .? Please let me know.

Comment: How to stop passing jwt token in header after logout?

Comment: Because now I am sending token in 'Authorization Header' using POSTMAN. So after logout too if anyone else send the same token in 'Authorization Header', then anyone can access the route as by jwt.decode, we get the id that exists in db. Please tell me how it can be done securely?